# 404 returned though rewrite rule is matched

Tags: apache-2.2, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have one rewrite rule that sends all requests to `index.php`:

```
RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php [NC,L]
```

*(Apart from `RewriteEngine On`, that's all there is in the `.htaccess` file)*

It works, unless the request path starts with `index/`, in which case the result is an `404 Not Found`.

If I change the filename of `index.php` to `index2.php` (and the rewrite rule to match it), it starts working again, so **clearly there's a conflict when the first segment of the requested path equals the first segment of the destination file**.

The `mod_rewrite` log contains this (when requesting `/index/hello`, which **fails**):

```
add path info postfix: /path/to/index.php -> /path/to/index.php/hello
strip per-dir prefix: /path/to/index.php/hello -> index.php/hello
applying pattern '^.*$' to uri 'index.php/hello'
rewrite 'index.php/hello' -> 'index.php'
add per-dir prefix: index.php -> /path/to/index.php
initial URL equal rewritten URL: /path/to/index.php [IGNORING REWRITE]
```

*(Some log info stripped out or modified for readability.)*

My server is `Apache/2.2.22`.

NB: This website, `.htaccess` file and `index.php` file included, has worked without problems until I reinstalled Debian on a new server, so I'm assuming there's some kind of config conflict or version bug that makes it happen now. I did not change any website files.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this:

```
Options -Multiviews
```

[they usually don't play very nice in combination with mod_rewrite](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/content-negotiation.html#multiviews)

BTW: if that's all you do currently, using the new-ish [`FallbackResource`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_dir.html#fallbackresource) might be more efficient. (Version >= 2.2.16).

Comment: @wrikkwn, Thank you, I added `Options -Multiviews` directly to the top of my `.htacces` file and it immediately started working again! I would have liked to solve things in a more elegant way, as you suggest, but it's not my own repository, so I'll just stick with this solution.